# Java: Why does the compiler complain here?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

```
  0          int specialFuncStart;
  1          String[] specialFunctions= {"sum","ddx","integral"};
  2          for(String element: specialFunctions){
  3              specialFuncStart = finalMath.lastIndexOf("sum");
  4          }
  5          while (specialFuncStart != -1) {   code  }
```

Why does `line 5` say that `specialFuncStart` might not have been initialized? Strings are final and fixed, so the for loop will always run. Does the compiler not know that or am I missing something? I understand that initializing `specialFuncStart = -1;` is how to fix it, but why?

Comment: Where is the variable specialFuncStar declared?

Comment: Add an =0  to that declaration.  Since your variable is only initialized in the for loop scope the compiler think that the for loop might not always run and there for the variable might not always be initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *declared* it but you didn't *initialize* it. You need to set a value to it:

```
int specialFuncStart; // declare
specialFuncStart = 0; // initialize

int specialFuncStart = 0; // both
```

Your compiler thinks that sometimes `specialFuncStart` will not be initialized since a `for` loop doesn't *have to* execute.

Comment: even if the code explicitly says the for loop will run? why does it do that?

Comment: @JohanZ. yes. Unfortunately compilers are not *that* smart yet. It can't notice that in compile-time. Try removing the "for" loop and see that the error will be removed.

Comment: It's not about the compiler's intelligence. The compiler can easily see that the loop is always run. It's just that the compiler is a bit lazy and instead of examining every case it just says "initialize your variable" to be safe.

Comment: @Kayaman you're right. I think it's more of an efficiency issue anyway

Comment: Pretty much. It's a lot easier to force initialization of variables than to write additional logic to the compiler for no real added value.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler shows error because you initialize the specialFuncStart variable in the for loop and compileris not  sure about whether it execute or not becuase 
in for-each loop array size can be 0 which makes it to not execute.

So you have initailise it before for loop like below to prevent error

`specialFuncStart = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop you check for a condition with a variable which was initialized within a scope of another loop. Compiler will not let you do that considering the scenarios like it may not get initialized properly, that loop may not run or it may break early, even when its clear from our perspective that events will happen perfectly.
The problem is with scopes, Java is a robust and strongly type language and its compiler checks every possibility to prevent misadventures.